# JOOQ - How to reference all Fields from several (but not all) tables in one query

Tags: mysql, kotlin, jooq

Given a query with multiple tables...

```
dsl.select(
    CUSTOMERS.ID,
    CUSTOMERS.NAME,
    CUSTOMRS.ADDRESS,
    ORDERS.ID,
    ORDERS.PRICE,
    ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID
    PRODUCTS.NAME,
.from(CUSTOMERS)
.join(ORDERS).on(ORDERS.ID.eq(CUSTOMERS.ORDER_ID))
.join(PRODUCTS).on(ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID.eq(PRODUCTS.ID))
.fetch()
```

Is there a way to write this query without listing all the column names in code? Specifically, is there a way to get all the columns from some tables, but only the specified columns from certain tables.

I'm interested in reducing the odds I forget to add new fields to my queries when I add new columns to a table. Additionally, I don't want to use `.asterik()` / `SELECT *` due to it's various classic issues that aren't fit for production.

Accordingly, is there something available like this imaginary example? Thanks!

```
dsl.select(
    CUSTOMERS.columns()
    ORDERS.columns()
    PRODUCTS.NAME,
.from(CUSTOMERS)
.join(ORDERS).on(ORDERS.ID.eq(CUSTOMERS.ORDER_ID))
.join(PRODUCTS).on(ORDERS.PRODUCT_ID.eq(PRODUCTS.ID))
.fetch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [`CUSTOMERS.fields()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Fields.html#fields()), etc. and pass them to individual `select()` calls:

```java
dsl.select(*CUSTOMERS.fields())
   .select(*ORDERS.fields())
   .select(PRODUCTS.NAME)
   ...
```

Or you can just [nest the `TableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-clause/select-clause-table/) if you prefer that:

```java
dsl.select(CUSTOMERS, ORDERS, PRODUCTS.NAME)
   ...
```

> I'm interested in reducing the odds I forget to add new fields to my queries when I add new columns to a table. Additionally, I don't want to use .asterik() / SELECT * due to it's various classic issues that aren't fit for production.

The tradeoff here is between you forgetting to add a column and you adding (way) too many irrelevant columns, which is a significant performance issue in many applications.

The `asterisk()` or `SELECT *` adds to that only a syntactic problem, namely that the order of columns in your production schema may not be as jOOQ's generated code expects.

[More info about `SELECT *`'s problems here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/dont-do-this/dont-do-this-sql-select-all/).

Comment: Ok great, thanks for the info! A few useful things I've picked up here -
 - you can use multiple select()
 - you can use the TebleRecord instead of specific fields
 - if using kotlin, you must also use the spread operator with fields() eg: `.select(*Customers.fields()`

Comment: @OffbeatUpbeat: Thanks for the hint. I've added the spread operator to my answer